# Not sure how to return a paticular value from json output

Tags: json

I have to extract "name" property from the following json output- Currently, following is how the json output shows-

```
  {
   "data":{
      "message":{
         "dashboard_config":{
            "dashboardType":"Single",
            "dashboardTitle":"RR",
            "noTabs":1,
            "tabsConfig":[
               {
                  "name":1,
                  "tooltip":"some other name and tooltip",
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I tried to do this

```
data.message.dashboard_config.tabsConfig[0].name
```

but for some reason it doesn't return the name property.
How would I extract "name" value from the above json output?

Comment: What is the variable name for the JSON object?

Comment: Well, what does it return? Another value, `undefined`...?

Comment: it's not returning anything